# outlook 2007 - is there a way to get the formatted text from an Appointmentitem?

Tags: com, outlook-2007

I'm trying to get the formatted text of the appointment item, I've searched everywhere and most places suggest getting the word document of the appointment item :

```
Word.Document wd = (Word.Document) (item as Outlook.AppointmentItem).GetInspector.WordEditor;
```

So I do that and I get the word document. But no where does it tell you what to actually do with this word document once you get it. How do I get the formatted text from the word document now?

UPDATE:
To anyone else searching for this answer in the future. I figured out how to do this in ol2007

1) First have have to get the word document from the appoint item via the WordEditor variable.

2) Then you have to use the select and copy functions from the word document to copy the RTF text into your clipboard.

3) make a richtextbox and use the richtextboc paste function to paste whats in the clipboard into your richtextbox.

4) now from the richtextbox you can access the .Rtf function which will now give you the RTF of the appointmentItem.

From my searching this method is the easiest way but you have to take over the clipboard which isn't ideal. There is a second way that I read about that is to save the word document in step 1 into an actually RTF file on your computer and then read in that RTF file.

and third way I suppose to do it would be to parse out the word document in step 1 using the Range.FormattedText function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: To anyone else searching for this answer in the future. I figured out how to do this in ol2007

1) First have have to get the word document from the appoint item via the WordEditor variable.

2) Then you have to use the select and copy functions from the word document to copy the RTF text into your clipboard.

3) make a richtextbox and use the richtextboc paste function to paste whats in the clipboard into your richtextbox.

4) now from the richtextbox you can access the .Rtf function which will now give you the RTF of the appointmentItem.

From my searching this method is the easiest way but you have to take over the clipboard which isn't ideal. There is a second way that I read about that is to save the word document in step 1 into an actually RTF file on your computer and then read in that RTF file.

and third way I suppose to do it would be to parse out the word document in step 1 using the Range.FormattedText function.